# I want to read and display the error message from my application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I intentionally produce the error message below ans I want to **validate that error message appears**.

The error message :-

[image: Error message:]

Here is my code:

```
addNewVen.clickOnCreateButton();
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div/div/p[3]/span"));
String textagain = name.getAttribute("value");
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you just look for it as for any other element on the page?

Comment: Any errors? Show us `HTML` for target element

Comment: What i want exactly is if the error appears test has to continue and then i will enter that field and proceed to next web element.

Comment: No error is coming @Andersson i just want to display that error message

Comment: I still don't get it :) Do you want to verify whether error message displayed if creation form is empty? correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct @Andersson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `isDisplayed` method that returns `True` if element is currently displayed on page and `False` otherwise:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div/div/p[3]/span[text()='Please enter Valid Company Name(Min 3 Chars)']")).isDisplayed();
```

or shorter option:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Please enter Valid Company Name(Min 3 Chars)']")).isDisplayed();
```

I suggest you not to use absolute `XPathes`, but relative instead

Let me know if this code not works

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways by which you can validate this error, I am giving an example for one of them.

**Example:**

If the error message is fixed you can first of all try to identify this element with the desired text.

```
WebElement errorMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[text()='Please enter Valid Company Name(Min 3 Chars)']));
```

Once you have the element identified, you can verify it with your `Assert` statement like:-

```
errorMsg.isDisplayed();
```

and return `true` or `false` based upon the results and do your validation.